# Selecting a Random Row on Google Sheets, Polpulating cells

Tags: google-sheets

I am new to coding and I am attempting to create a spreadsheet that generates a 'Call' based on the information pulled from a cell.

Each row Contains the following:

Call Type, Call Grade, Call Description

I need to randomly select a row and then populate the cells on a different sheet with the information from that row?

I would appreciate any help"!

Thanks,

Anthony

Answer (score 0):

Assuming four columns A:D and a dozen rows starting at the top, you might use something like:

```
=index(importrange(" k e y ","A1:D12"),RANDBETWEEN(1,12))
```

which will require authorisation.